# CSS - Two flex columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am working on redesigning a web page with a structure looking like this

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 700px;
  background-color: grey;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container__txt {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.container-block {
  display: flex;
  width: calc(50% - 9px);
  background-color: red;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__txt">I am a text div</div>
  <div class="container-block">I am a block div</div>
  <div class="container-block">I am a block div</div>
 </div>
```

I try to obtain a certain behaviour. I'd like the blocks to be full width if and only if the other block is not here.

I can't really find a good solution because the container has another child which is the text div. I cannot touch the html structure nor add js; therefore the solution must be pure CSS.

If someone has an idea on how to achieve this, I would ge gratefull.

I hope I didn't miss an aspect of the problem.

Comment: You seem to be lacking any actual `flex` rules. `flex: 1 0 100%` for the top column, `flex: 1 1 auto;` for the rest. Done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `flex: 1` on your `.container-block` should fix your problem :

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 700px;
  background-color: grey;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container__txt {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.container-block {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}

.container-block + .container-block {
  margin-left: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__txt">I am a text div</div>
  <div class="container-block">I am a block div</div>
  <div class="container-block">I am a block div</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="container__txt">I am a text div</div>
  <div class="container-block">I am a block div</div>
</div>
```

You can learn more about the flex property [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp).

Comment: I didn't think about the ".container-block + .container-block" rule. Your solution is just fine. Thx !

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  background-color: grey;
}

.container__txt {
   display: flex;
  background-color: green;
}

.container__div {
   display: flex;
  background-color: green;
}

.container-block {
  display: flex;
  flex:1;
  background-color: red;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
    <div class="container__txt">I am a text div</div>
    <div class="container__div">
      <div class="container-block">I am a block div</div>
      <div class="container-block">I am a block div</div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <br>
 <br>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container__txt">I am a text div</div>
    <div class="container__div">
      <div class="container-block">I am a block div</div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/t8h671eb/11/

Try this code. It works fine.

Comment: @XanX3601, Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: I tried something like this but with this solution, the middle space is lost

Comment: @XanX3601, You can use :nth-child property and add a gap there. check below fidlle.
https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/t8h671eb/20/